# trigger in oracle allows insert if field is found

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have three tables called products, customers and reserve_products. The trigger is on the reserve products table and will only let you insert into the table if the customer id and product id and quantity of product is found and not 0. I am having problems with the sql and checking if the rows exist.

My tables are as follows:
**products**

```
CREATE TABLE "SNAGEL"."PRODUCTS" 
   (    "PID" NUMBER(6,0), 
    "PRODUCT_NAME" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
    "QUANTITY" NUMBER, 
    "PRICE" NUMBER, 
    "PRODUCT_SIZE" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
    "PRODUCT_VALUE" NUMBER, 
     PRIMARY KEY ("PID")
```

**Customers**

```
 CREATE TABLE "SNAGEL"."CUSTOMERS" 
   (    "CID" NUMBER(6,0), 
    "FIRST_NAME" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "LAST_NAME" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "PHONE_NUMBER" NUMBER, 
     PRIMARY KEY ("CID")
```

**Reserve Product**

**my trigger**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER reserveProductTrigger
    before insert on RESERVE_PRODUCT FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  pid products.pid%rowtype;
  pidError exception;
  cid customers.cid%rowtype;
  cidError exception;
  pidSoldout exception;
  productQuantity number;
BEGIN
  select cid from CUSTOMERS 
  where cid = :new.CID;

  select COUNT(pid from products
  where pid = :new.PID;

  select quantity into productQuantity 
  from products
  where pid= :new.pid;

  if cid = null then
    raise cidError;
  elsif pid = null then
    raise pidError;
  elsif productQuantity = 0 then
    raise pidSoldout;
  else
    update products
    set quantity = productQuantity -1
    where pid = pid;
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  When cidError then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CUSTOMER not found error!');
    RAISE;
  When PidError then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PRODUCT not found error!');
    RAISE;
  When pidSoldout then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('product sold out error!');
    RAISE;
END;
/
```

Comment: Please, provide minimal example. I.e. if you want to check existence of rows in some table, try and leave only one table in example, not three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_reserve_products
BEFORE INSERT ON reserve_products
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  v_count NUMBER;
  v_p_id NUMBER(6);
  v_c_id NUMBER(6);
  v_p_quantity products.p_quantity%TYPE;
  v_p_name products.p_name%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO v_count
  FROM products
  WHERE p_id = :NEW.p_id;
  IF v_count = 0 THEN
    raise_application_error(-20000 , 'Invalid Product ID.');
  END IF;

  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO v_count
  FROM customers
  WHERE c_id = :NEW.c_id;
  IF v_count IS NULL THEN
    raise_application_error(-20000 , 'Invalid Customer ID.');
  END IF; 
  
  SELECT p_quantity, p_name
  INTO v_p_quantity, v_p_name
  FROM products
  WHERE p_id = :NEW.p_id;  
  IF v_p_quantity < 1 THEN
    raise_application_error(-20000 , v_p_name || ' 4 is currently out of stock.');
  END IF; 
  
  UPDATE products
  SET p_quantity = p_quantity - 1
  WHERE p_id = :NEW.p_id;
END trg_reserve_products;

SELECT * FROM products;

INSERT INTO reserve_products VALUES(1, 101, 1);
INSERT INTO reserve_products VALUES(2, 46, 1);
INSERT INTO reserve_products VALUES(3, 46, 2);
INSERT INTO reserve_products VALUES(4, 46, 3);

SELECT * FROM products;

SELECT * FROM reserve_products;
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to store the details from your select statements into the variables yoiu created for them.  So try this instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER reserveProductTrigger
    before insert on RESERVE_PRODUCT FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  pid products.pid%type;
  pidError exception;
  cid customers.cid%type;
  cidError exception;
  pidSoldout exception;
  productQuantity number;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    select cid into CID
      from CUSTOMERS 
    where cid = :new.CID;
  EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    raise cidError;
  END;

  BEGIN
    select pid
         , quantity
      INTO PID
         , productQuantity
      from products
    where pid = :new.PID;
  EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    raise pidError;
  END;

  if productQuantity <= 0 then -- If it goes negative you've over
    raise pidSoldout;             -- committed and shouldn't accept either.
  else
    update products
    set quantity = productQuantity -1
    where pid = pid;
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  When cidError then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CUSTOMER not found error!');
    RAISE;
  When PidError then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PRODUCT not found error!');
    RAISE;
  When pidSoldout then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('product sold out error!');
    RAISE;
END;
/
```

However, rather than relying on the trigger to check on the existence of PID and CID, you should use referential integrity constraints.  Additionally you can put a check constraint on the Quantity column in Products requiring it to be >= 0.

Then the only thing you need to do in your trigger is decrement the Quantity:

```
CREATE TABLE "PRODUCTS" 
   (    "PID" NUMBER(6,0), 
    "PRODUCT_NAME" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
    "QUANTITY" NUMBER CONSTRAINT PRODUCT_MIN_QUANTITY CHECK (QUANTITY >= 0), -- Add Check constraint here
    "PRICE" NUMBER, 
    "PRODUCT_SIZE" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
    "PRODUCT_VALUE" NUMBER, 
     CONSTRAINT PRODUCTS_PK PRIMARY KEY ("PID") -- Name the PK Constraint
     );

CREATE TABLE "CUSTOMERS" 
   (    "CID" NUMBER(6,0), 
    "FIRST_NAME" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "LAST_NAME" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "PHONE_NUMBER" NUMBER, 
     CONSTRAINT CUSTOMERS_PK PRIMARY KEY ("CID") -- Name the PK Constraint
     );

create table reserve_product (
  PID NOT NULL CONSTRAINT reserve_product_fk REFERENCES products(PID)  -- Use referential integrity here
, CID NOT NULL CONSTRAINT reserve_product_fk REFERENCES customers(CID) -- and here
)

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER reserveProductTrigger
    before insert on RESERVE_PRODUCT FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    update products
    set quantity = quantity -1
    where pid = :new.pid;
END;
/
```

Now if either PID or CID is missing from Products or Customers respectivly, or if the Products record has a quantity of 0, appropriate exceptions will be raised.

Comment: i get this error: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 14
00604. 00000 -  "error occurred at recursive SQL level %s"
*Cause:    An error occurred while processing a recursive SQL statement
           (a statement applying to internal dictionary tables).

Comment: There is no recursive SQL in any of the above code.

Comment: i needed to do a Select COUNT(*)